# How to resolve error displayed by Valgrind "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

Tags: c, valgrind

I am writing program in **C** to load dictionary and then check provided file for misspellings. Function to load dictionary uses **hash bucket** and **chaining rule** to resolve collisions. Chains are made from **linked lists**:

```
#define LENGTH 45

    typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;
```

Everything is working perfectly, except when I check the code with Valgrind. There is no memory leaks, but there seems to be error in using uninitialized value:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    by 0x109B8F: load (dictionary.c:111)
    by 0x10929B: main (speller.c:40)
  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    by 0x109B21: load (dictionary.c:96)
    by 0x10929B: main (speller.c:40)
```

I repeatedly debugged code narrowing down source of this error to my **function responsible for loading** dictionary to heap. To be more exact problem seem to be in **creating temporary pointer for new node** and then **trying to access word variable inside** node even when the word is copied from another char table and initialized:

```
node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node)); // Error source (line 96)

if (temp == NULL)
{
   return false;
}

temp->next = NULL;

for (int i = 0; word_buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    temp->word[i] = word_buffer[i];
}

int key = hash(temp->word); // Error in using temp->word, not initialised (line 111)
```

**How can I change these lines of code to resolve Valgrind error?**
Can you explains source of this error? I only recently started my programming journey and want to know to avoid this error in future

Here is Minimal, Reproducible Example

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 45

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;


int main(void)
{
    char word_buffer[LENGTH + 1] = {'C', 'A', 'T'};

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node)); // Error source

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    temp->next = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; word_buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        temp->word[i] = word_buffer[i];
    }

    if (temp->word[0] == '\0') // Error in using temp->word, not initialised
    {
        return 2;
    }

    printf("%s\n", temp->word);

    free(temp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Sure, give me some time tho, I need to reduce some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown fails to add a null terminator to `temp->word`. Supposing that `hash` expects to receive a null-terminated string, the lack of a null terminator would cause `hash` to read uninitialized elements in `temp->word`.

This could be fixed by changing:

```
for (int i = 0; word_buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    temp->word[i] = word_buffer[i];
}
```

to:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; word_buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    temp->word[i] = word_buffer[i];
}
temp->word[i] = '\0';
```

although it should be noted the code shown has no guard against exceeding the length of `temp->word` array.

Comment: So it was problem with lack of NUL.  Thank you very much!

Comment: When I was using debugger char table word showed me it was filled with NULs so I assumed I don't need to add one manually. Good to know!

Comment: When memory is uninitialized it will still contain some value. That value might be 0, but it might not. Unfortunately this can lead a lot of programmers to falsely conclude that their code is OK.